# two tabs or more using shinydashboard package

Tags: r, shinydashboard

can any one build in that below very simple shiny dashboard another tab where we can have other sliderbar, other output.....etc.i am realy confused.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Tab1"),
  dashboardSidebar(    width = 230,
sidebarMenu(
  fileInput("df",
              label="Upload FCM Data"
              ),
  fileInput("dl",
            label="Upload Device AX Data"
  ),
  
  uiOutput('choose_TEC'),
  uiOutput('choose_OP'),
  uiOutput('choose_APL'),
  uiOutput('choose_PRD'),
  uiOutput('choose_DEV'),
  uiOutput('choose_NACol')
)),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Z B, where do you want the tab, in the header, sidebar?

Comment: @Quinten May be i did not ask a clear queation .In fact using shiny packgaes there were the possibiliy to have multiple pages with owen title and when you click one of them you find user inputs, functionalities ......etc .I want the same with shinydashboard package which seems impossible .i mean i need multiple(>2) dashboardpages .each one of then hat its owen sidebar and its owen outputs .I do no mean tabbox .I hope you understood me.

Comment: For the sidebar you can try `shinydashboard::renderMenu()`

Answer (score 1):

I created just an example dashboard with two tabs using `tabPanel`. You can use the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage("Dashboard", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                  tabPanel("Tab1",
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               fileInput("df",
                                         label="Upload FCM Data"
                               ),
                               fileInput("dl",
                                         label="Upload Device AX Data"
                               ),
                               
                               uiOutput('choose_TEC'),
                               uiOutput('choose_OP'),
                               uiOutput('choose_APL'),
                               uiOutput('choose_PRD'),
                               uiOutput('choose_DEV'),
                               uiOutput('choose_NACol')
                             ),
                             mainPanel(
                               h2("text tab 1")
                             )
                           )
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Tab 2",
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider"), min = 0, 
                                           max = 100, value = 50)
                             ),
                             mainPanel(
                               h2("text tab2")
                             )
                           )
                  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So can we say that shinydashboard library can not achieve whta i wanted to do.Because i see you have used other package with and you have used other functions